Go through vs go past: best translation?
If you ask Google to translate
"I ran past the department store"
and
"I ran through the department store"
the output is the same "我跑過百貨公司"
How would you translate it so as to highlight the difference?

Oh dear, AI can't cope with the difference between through and past!
I ran past the department store.
我跑着路过百货商店。
I ran through the department store.
我跑着穿过百货商店。

I ran "past" a department store - 我跑步"經過"一家百貨公司 (You were running on the street in front of the store)
"I ran "through" the department store" - 我跑步"通過"那家百貨公司 (You were running across/inside the store from one entrance to the other)

ran past and ran through are two different things. When you are running on the street and passing the department store on your way, you are running past it. When you run into the department store from one end and run out from the other end, you run through it.

"I ran past the department store" can be translated as "我跑步經過一家百貨公司"  (can be reduced to 我跑經一家百貨公司 or  我跑過一家百貨公司)

"I ran through the department store" should be translated as “我跑步穿過一家百貨公司” (reduce it to 我跑過一家百貨公司 would cause ambiguity; reduce it to 我跑穿一家百貨公司 sound unnatural)



“路過" might be a more precise choice here

經過 and 路過 are both correct for passing, not 穿過

經過 has more abstract meaning than 路過, it might be used more often in some specific dialect, but in mainland madarin it's rarely used like this in daily dialog. And also 經過 can express "through" like 我跑步經過公園, it's hard to tell whether you ran though the park or past the park (a bit more tending to "through", but that's why I say it's rarely used in daily dialog)

@KassianSun "經"為"道", "道"為"路"; 經過 = 路過. "through" means 通过, 穿过, 贯穿.

@r13 No, Chinese doesn't work like this xD
